# Log rotation of stdout on Windows?

Tags: windows, logs

I am looking for a tool that would allow me to rotate logs produced by apps on their `stdout` and/or `stderr`. I know about the "https://superuser.com/questions/291368/log-rotation-of-stdout" but that question and its answers only talk about *NIX tools. Are there any such tools for pure Windows (i.e., no Cygwin)?